# How to partition by key and join back in order with Elixir Flow

Tags: elixir

I am trying to wrap my head around `Flow` to build a parallel processing pipe with the following characteristics:

1. Incoming events have the form `{offset, %{"id" => id}}`
2. `offset` is an monotonically incrementing integer
3. `id` is an arbitrary number
4. I only need to retain the order for every `id`, so different ids can be computed out of order in parallel. Hence the partition.

Here is an example stream to generate an infinite amount of these tuples:

```
stream = Stream.unfold(1, fn i ->
  offset = i+1
  element = {offset, %{"id" => Enum.random(1..10_000)}}
  {element, offset}
end)
```

I want to partition the stream by they key `id`. I know how to do that and for example start 8 parallel stages:

```
Flow.from_enumerable(stream)
|> Flow.partition(
  key: fn {_, m} -> Map.get(m, "id") end,
  stages: 8
)
```

Every operation I follow in this flow is now happening in parallel, order is only kept by the partition key `id`.

#### Now what I do not understand: How to join back the stream into a single stage, ordered by `offset`?

To be clear, this is an infinite stream, so we need to keep in mind that we need to join over window (I have tried multiple ways. After all a timeout of 10 seconds is fine to start dropping events that do not arrive timely from processing).

Here is an illustration how I image it should work:

```
INCOMING
|
V
* PARTIONING in N-stages by `id`
|\
|-\
|--\
|||| PARALLEL PROCESSING in order by `id`
|--/
|-/
|/
| JOIN in order by `offset`
| timing out after 10 seconds, moving on with the smallest known offset
|
| SEQUENTIAL PROCESSING of each offset of the JOIN
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the result of each partition. We usually partition to aggregate a final result but you haven't described what this final result may be. Could you please expand?

Comment: Each partition just acts on each event, and does not modify the data. So one incoming event has the form `{123, %{"id" => 4567}}` and is never modified till the end.

Comment: So why are you partitioning? :) You only need partitioning when you need to aggregate the data and the routing is a relevant aspect of that data.

Comment: Because I want to process the data in parallel, yet in sequence for each bucket/partition. So that no two of the same ids process in parallel, only distinct ids. Or in other words, the same ids all process one after the other. Yet, I might be misunderstanding how `Flow.partition` is used here.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I think I have all of the "specs" now, let me think about it and I will get back to you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The joining part can be done by calling `partition/2` once again but setting the number of stages to 1.

Here is a sample script that reproduces your use case by emitting tuples with offsets and random partitions:

```
1..10000
|> Stream.map(fn i -> {i, Enum.random([:a, :b, :c, :d])} end)
|> Flow.from_enumerable()
|> Flow.partition(key: {:elem, 1})
|> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end, fn x, acc -> [process_x(x) | acc] end)
|> Flow.emit(:state)
|> Flow.partition(stages: 1)
|> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end, &Kernel.++/2)
|> Flow.map_state(&Enum.sort/1)
|> Flow.emit(:state)
|> Enum.to_list()
|> IO.inspect
```

The tricky part is in partitioning. **Once you partition, you have to accumulate state**.

So after the first partition, we call `Flow.reduce/3`, processing the elements and then putting them on the top of a list. Processing is done by calling `process_x` which you will have to implement. Once you have processed all entries, we ask to emit the whole partition state, i.e. a list of events, to the next step.

Then we partition again, but this time into a single stage, that simply concatenates the results of the previous partitions and then sort them at the end.

Another point not considered in my example above is that your flow is infinite, so you need to add some windows. You need to choose how frequently to emit items from each partition. For the first partition, you can emit batches of 1000 elements. For the joined partition, you mentioned you want it to happen every 10 seconds. So let's add those in.

Finally, note the code above is not the most efficient because everything that runs in the last partition is serial (a single stage). Ideally you want to sort in the first partition and simply merge the sorted results in the last partition, with the help of a `merge_sorted` function that you would define.

Here is the final result:

```
partition_window = Flow.Window.global |> Flow.Window.trigger_every(1000, :reset)
join_window = Flow.Window.global |> Flow.Window.trigger_periodically(10, :second, :reset)

1..10000
|> Stream.map(fn i -> {i, Enum.random([:a, :b, :c, :d])} end)
|> Flow.from_enumerable()
|> Flow.partition(key: {:elem, 1}, window: partition_window)
|> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end, fn x, acc -> [process_x(x) | acc] end)
|> Flow.map_state(&Enum.sort/1)
|> Flow.emit(:state)
|> Flow.partition(stages: 1, window: join_window)
|> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end, &merge_sorted/2)
|> Flow.emit(:state)
|> Enum.to_list()
|> IO.inspect
```